# Bootstrap Material Datepicker do not pop up in ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a form which creates date field dynamically which is suppose to call material datepicker (jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.date1').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ weekStart : 0, time: false });
    $.material.init();
</script>
<div ng-repeat="JobExp in jobpostings">
    <div class="form-group-md pull-right">
        <input type="text"  class="date1 form-control" ng-model="JobExp.posting_date">
    </div>
</div>
```

It works absolutely fine when I do not use ng-repeat.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.date1').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ weekStart : 0, time: false });
    $.material.init();
</script>
<div class="form-group-md pull-right">
    <input type="text"  class="date1 form-control" ng-model="JobExp.posting_date">
</div>
```

It pops up the desired datepicker when I use only one datepicker but to open datepicker when I use ng-repeat.
I used class instead of giving Ids to input type but still the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because when you call the script ng-repeat hasn't rendered yet, so there is no element with class `data1` you might need to wait for ng-repeat to render and preferably move the script to angular service

```
//call in controller when model for ng-repeat has been retrieved
function createDatepicker(){
  $scope.$applyAsync(function(){
    $('.date1').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ weekStart : 0, time: false });
    $.material.init();
  })
}
```

instead of `applyAsync` you can use `$timeout` without time specified, that will assure that function is called in next digest cycle after ng-repeat has been rendered

Comment: And how do I call this  with ng-click?

Comment: you assign that function to a scope variable and call it in ng-click, although if you think it will work on first click - it wont, because on first click you would create the datepicker and elements `date1` will not have the click handler yet to open the datepicker, it's better to use it after data loading